# the specifications graph showing the battery discharges in volt per time

Tags: irobot-create

my name is dylan we are doing a project on irobot create and we would like to know the specifications graph showing the battery discharges in volt per time and my robot is the irobot ceate 1.

The battery is the roomba advanced power , it's a 14.4V Nickel metal hybride battery pack and she deliver 3000mah.

Comment: Under what conditions?  The battery will discharge at very different rates depending on many conditions including which motors are running and at what PWM, the floor type, the payload, etc.

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of factors that affect battery voltage of NiMH batteries during discharge versus time.  Discharge rate, battery temperature, and battery age are all major contributing factors.  As a result there is no one graph of battery voltage vs. time, there are usually a family of curves.

You could characterize the battery you have by measuring the voltage at specific time intervals during a discharge and build the graph yourself.  Be aware that if you change the load current you will need to make a new characterization.  As the battery ages the internal resistance increases so your initial characterization will become progressively inaccurate.

How do you plan to use this information?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I hope to use this information for my school project.